# I need to convert a number from base 255 to base 256

Tags: delphi

I have a file that contains numbers stored in base 255. So, I need to convert a number from base 255 to base 256.  The number is a cardinal.

Hint: Base 255 means each byte contain numbers from 0 to 254 instead of 0 to 255 as would happen if the number will be 'normal' (base 256).

---

There are any low level routines (like bit rotations) to do this?

Comment: I don't really get the question... It sounds like you are using a position system with 255 digits (0-9, A-Z, ???) and want to convert such a number to another system with 256 digits...

Comment: Hi Andreas. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Altar: I'm sorry -- I still don't get it. In my world, a byte always represent any one of the 256 distinct numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., 255.

Comment: OK, now that I see Lasse's answer, I think I understand what you wish to achieve.

Comment: It is indeed strange, but sometimes people to like to use this kind of 'strange mathematics' :)

Comment: @Altar: There is a lot of unexplained downvoting in the Delphi tag (at least). It's a pity.

Comment: I'm curious, what's the purpose here?

Comment: @David. I got a file that is encoded that way. I need to read it.

Comment: @David. Don't tell me :) They wanted to use $FF as separator for some strings so they shifted the bytes in the entire file. The file was designed by a big big corporation (I won't tell the name here).

Comment: @Altar that is bizarre. Some serious wheel re-invention going on there!

Comment: @David. I will start reading the file soon. If the content decodes ok then it is true: they indeed used base 255.

Comment: @Altar I trust you'll be able to read the file in very quickly!!  ;-)

Comment: @David. I have done it. It works. Actually I was afraid that my supposition might not be true. But now, finally, the files decoded correctly. It took me few days until I realized the trick (the use of 255 base). So, yes, they use a square wheel. Decoding a 5MB file takes about 1.5-2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right, you need something like this (I use Delphi 2009+ Exit syntax):

```
function GetLongWord255(Source: LongWord; var Target: LongWord): Boolean;
var
  B: Byte;

begin
  B:= Byte(Source shr 24);
  if B = 255 then Exit(False);
  Target:= B;
  B:= Byte(Source shr 16);
  if B = 255 then Exit(False);
  Target:= Target * 255 + B;
  B:= Byte(Source shr 8);
  if B = 255 then Exit(False);
  Target:= Target * 255 + B;
  B:= Byte(Source);
  if B = 255 then Exit(False);
  Target:= Target * 255 + B;
  Exit(True);
end;
```

As for low-level tricks, you can use

```
Target * 255 = Target shl 8 - Target;
```

though I am not sure you can gain by it. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have 4 bytes, each in base 255, ie. "almost a byte".

To calculate the sum, do this:

```
sum = b1 + (b2 + (b3 + b4 * 255) * 255) * 255
```

You have to decide if b1 is the leftmost or rightmost byte, depending on the endianess of the values.

You can rewrite the above like this, to make it easier to understand:

```
sum  = b1
sum += b2 * 255
sum += b3 * 255 * 255
sum += b4 * 255 * 255 * 255
```

Comment: My question is how this shouldn't be elementary math to you. To sum up any number written out in base N, you can replace the above 255 with any N, such as ... 10.

Comment: I just hoped there is a dedicated function (like those bit level operators) to do it so it won't involve so much computations. I updated the post about 15 minutes after I post it to better reflect my question. But as David says, this is indeed strange so I guess Intel didn't bother to implement a low level function to do this.

Comment: Result := Result + BitValue * (Base ^ BitPosition) where BitPosition = 0 for the LSB.

Comment: @Lasse, really? Wouldn't this be correct: Result := b1*(255^0) + b2*(255^1) + b3*(255^2) + b4*(255^3)

Comment: Argh.... I misunderstood/misread your comment. Of course that is correct. I need more coffee it seems. Sorry about that.